# Is Google Drive a good data storage solution for a web app?

Tags: amazon-s3, google-drive-api

I'm thinking about using Google Drive as a scalable cloud based data storage solution (Like Amazon S3) for a web application I'm working on. Would Google Drive be a good solution in this respect?

Comment: I don't get why this is not constructive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't talk for Amazon S3, but data store on Google Drive is owned by the user and not the application.

So it really depends on the use-case your web application has, if you want the user to own the data and be able to open the data with other application, use Google Drive.

If the data should be hidden from the user, you can use other cloud storage solutions.

Comment: Ya, it's similar to dropbox in that respect isn't it. Dang!

Comment: You can use S3 and have the data owned by the user too. S3 has support for corporate - like permissions, restrictions, etc.